# how to override font color style of header element in css

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML which cannot be changed:

```
<h5 class="post-title">Welcome To The Site</h5>
```

I want to make the font red.  I tried the following:

```
.post-title{
    color:red ! important; 
}
```

but this did not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `h5.post-title{  color:red ! important;  }`

Comment: This is not valid html... there is a </a> tag whithin <h5> that should not be there

Answer (score 1):

Well, without seeing the rest of your styles, it's hard to tell what's overriding what. However, I'm going to take a leap here and assume this issue is the random close `</a>` tag you got there.

Answer (score 0):

You're having a tag in your code that's never opened, and so your HTML is malformed. (`</a>`)

If you use your code as shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hvcsgwkc/) example, with the exact same code (without the obsolete closing tag), it does work, you can even drop the `!important` tag as it's not necessary.

Comment: you cannot be sure, that !important is not neccessary, but the </a> tag is most likely causing the issue

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but it's the only thing I can assume from what the guy posted, and I believe it answers the question.

Comment: (however, with both the `! important` [note the space] and the `</a>`, my browser was able to render the color just fine.)